# How to set the universal CSS selector with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I often use the CSS universal selector to reset the dimensions in my HTML document:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Can this be done with JavaScript too?

For normal HTML elements there is the `style` property.
But how to speak to the universal selector?

Comment: @OneTrickPony This needs jQuery...

Comment: Why JavaScript at all?

Comment: I need it to init some JavaScript performance tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName("*")` will return all elements from DOM. Then you may set styles for each element in the collection:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = allElements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];
    // element.style.border = ...
}
```

Comment: Fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only/15903168

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to iterate all the elements. You can demand this operation to the CSS engine of your browser. Something like that:

```
;(function(exports) {
  var style = document.querySelector("head")
                      .appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

  var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
  styleSheet.insertRule("* {}", 0);

  exports.universal = styleSheet.cssRules[0];
}(window));
```

From now, you have a `window.universal` object that you can use to style all the elements. For instance:

```
window.universal.style.border = "1px solid red";
```

Of course you don't need to create at runtime the `<style>` tag. You can always have that in plain HTML too.

You can test it running this snippet:

```js
;(function(exports) {
  var style = document.querySelector("head")
                      .appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

  var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
  styleSheet.insertRule("* {}", 0);

  exports.universal = styleSheet.cssRules[0];
}(window));

console.log("universal" in window); // true

window.universal.style.border = "1px solid red";
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
  <span>World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: window.universal is undefined` showing in Firefox 86.0.1 when using `window.universal.style.border = "1px solid red";`

Comment: Did you run the script that creates the `window.universal` object? I ran in Firefox 86 and 88 and it's still working (although it's a very old code and I wouldn't do something like that nowadays).
If you try to access to `window.universal` without the script above it won't work.

Comment: well, i added the code inside `<script>` tag in the main html file, probably in the header tag (changed the code, so don't remember) and after loading the page, that error shows in the browser console. Don't understand why.

Comment: I added a snippet in the original answer so you can test it. I don't know the details to your code so I cannot debug it. But it looks like when you try to access `window.universal` you don't have execute the snippet to create it yet.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it works, I probably missed the function workarounds it the previous code

Answer (score 2):

In raw javascript you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*')
```

but I wouldn't recommend adding css to all elements using js.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **VisioN** for the solution! I just remembered that you can do the same with the new JavaScript Query Selector API:

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var element = allElements[i];        
  element.style.border = '0px';
  element.style.margin = '0px';
  element.style.padding = '0px';
}
```

Comment: Definitely you can use `querySelectorAll`, however you have to consider possible compatibility problems.