# override local css variable with global variable

Tags: html, css, css-variables

Is it possible to override the local CSS variable with a global variable?
As we know vice-versa is always possible. Can someone help if there is anything like `!important` to override the local variable.

Taking the below example, want `red` to have more precedence than `blue`.

```css
 :root{
    --primarycolor: red !important; /*Like this*/
  }
  body {
    color: var(--primarycolor);
    border:2px solid var(--primarycolor);
    padding:5px;
  }
  div{
    --primarycolor: blue; /*Want to override this*/
    color: var(--primarycolor);
    border:2px solid var(--primarycolor);
    padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
Check all border color - I am in body
<div>I am in div</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such feature in CSS. Instead what you can do is to use fallback values `var(--primary-color, blue);`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Custom_property_fallback_values

Comment: don't define the local variable then

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually I update the global variable with JS dynamically. Thank you I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `:root` use `*`. It won't be a global variable but still declared as a *global* one that will apply to all the element (instead of being inherited by all the element)

```css
* {
  --primarycolor: red !important; /*Like this*/
}

body {
  color: var(--primarycolor);
  border: 2px solid var(--primarycolor);
  padding: 5px;
}

div {
  --primarycolor: blue; /*Want to override this*/
  color: var(--primarycolor);
  border: 2px solid var(--primarycolor);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
Check all border color - I am in body
<div>I am in div</div>
```

And without important the local one will apply since it's more specific:

```css
* {
  --primarycolor: red;
}

body {
  color: var(--primarycolor);
  border: 2px solid var(--primarycolor);
  padding: 5px;
}

div {
  --primarycolor: blue; 
  color: var(--primarycolor);
  border: 2px solid var(--primarycolor);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
Check all border color - I am in body
<div>I am in div</div>
```

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14791415/8620333